# Populate default MYSQL value in a html Dropdown list

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to update the `user_pref` column within my html form.

I have a drop down which looks like this (it works fine):

```
User pref: <select name="user_pref" size="1" id="user_pref">
<option value="BLUE">Blue</option>
<option value="RED">Red</option>
<option value="YELLOW">Yellow</option>
<?php echo htmlentities($user_pref, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?></select>
```

I want to be able to set the default value to the value the user already has in the `user_pref`column in MySQL. So, for example ,if user A has `"Yellow"` in their user_pref then I want to display `"Yellow"` when I'm updating that user's preference.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: So you add `selected="selected"` to the option you want to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic idea... you'll have to adapt it to fit your needs...

```
<?php

    // assuming $user_pref is their preference...

    /*
     * create array of possible options...
     * I usually store my options in my database because
     * my applications tend to be dynamic
     * but you can just create a quick array to do the same job
     */
    $arrOptions = array(
        'val1' => 'option1',
        'val2' => 'option2',
        'val3' => 'option3'
    );

    $selected = '';

    print '<select id="user_pref_id">';

    foreach ($arrOptions as $key => $val) {
        // test for $key or $val depending on which makes sense for your application
        $selected = ($key == $user_pref) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

        printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $key, $selected, $val);
    }

    print '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: This actually worked ! Thank you ! Although the code gives errors now when I try to update